# Late 80s/early 90s movie about a portal to another world/dimension

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I remember was it used to be on HBO/Cinemax all the time in the late 80s/early 90s.

**Things I remember**: The main character was a dork. It was revealed he had asked a cute neighbor out and was rejected. I remember him looking out the window and he could see her being picked up for a date by another guy.

He picked up a computer/or a mirror that turns out was (unknown to him) a portal to another world.

It sucked him and his friends though, and they were sent to a Sci-Fi/wild west type town (like in the universe of the TV show *Firefly*.

Some half human, half androidish bad guy and his posse eventually came and they had a fight.

The bad guys captured the nerd's friend  and a girl (she was from the wild west town and the main character had a crush on her.)

I remember the main character hid and realized there was a mirror in one of the buildings that was the portal back to Earth and he ran into it, going back home to Earth.

At one point when he was back home, he was staring back at the portal trying to get the courage to go back and rescue his friends and the girl.

He finally got the courage and jumped through, got some guns, rescued his friends and the girl from the bad guys and saved the day.

It ended with him staying back in the wild west town with the girl and his friends went back home.

I realize it has some similarities to [*House II*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_II:_The_Second_Story), but it is not *House II*.

I've been trying to find this movie *for years*. I've had no luck. Now I'm starting to think, maybe it was an episode of some kind of anthology TV show like *The Outer Limits* or something.

Does anyone have any clue what I'm talking about?

Comment: I assumed it was House II

Comment: See if this rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Crossworlds